# Minimizing Memory Consumption on sscanf

Tags: c, parsing, memory, scanf

I have a time&date string acquired from a GSM module.

Here is the time&date format:

```
"yy/MM/dd,hh:mm:ss±zz"
```

And an example string:

```
"+CCLK: "17/04/07,12:57:43+03""
```

I need to parse it and convert it to Unix Timestamp. I have the below implementation for it and it works well:

Time Struct:

```
struct timeStruct{

uint16 Year;
uint8 Month;
uint8 Day;
uint8 Hour;
uint8 Minute;
uint8 Second;
};
```

GSM Clock Command Parser:

```
void load_clock(void)
{

struct timeStruct gsmTimeStruct;

/* Parse year,month,day,hour,minute,second and GMT timezone */
sscanf(gsm_clk_string, "+CCLK: \"%hd/%d/%d,%d:%d:%d%c%d", &(gsmTimeStruct.Year), &(gsmTimeStruct.Month), &(gsmTimeStruct.Day), &(gsmTimeStruct.Hour), &(gsmTimeStruct.Minute), &(gsmTimeStruct.Second),&CONEZONE,&TIMEZONE);

unixTime = (uint32_t)RTC_DateTimeToUnix(gsmTimeStruct);

/* Collect GMT difference */
if(CONEZONE == '+')
    unixTime = unixTime - TIMEZONE*3600;
else
    unixTime = unixTime + TIMEZONE*3600;

}
```

That `sscanf` function consumes 1776 Bytes from the Flash Memory which is a huge number for this MCU. The Unix conversion function also consumes about 700 Bytes but it is a bit normal as it has some mathematical calculations in it.

Are there any bright ideas on parsing this string without consuming such big flash memory usage?

Note: The error checking for the Command String is not an issue since the GSM module already does it. So, if we want to change the parsing implementation, we don't have to do it. We can just assume those numbers are always there.

Edit: I tried below snippet, it works well. It saved 1.7 kilobytes memory but I'm not sure if this is a proper way.

```
gsmTimeStruct.Year      = (gsm_clk_string[8]-'0')*10 + (gsm_clk_string[9]-'0');
gsmTimeStruct.Month     = (gsm_clk_string[11]-'0')*10 + (gsm_clk_string[12]-'0');
gsmTimeStruct.Day       = (gsm_clk_string[14]-'0')*10 + (gsm_clk_string[15]-'0');
gsmTimeStruct.Hour      = (gsm_clk_string[17]-'0')*10 + (gsm_clk_string[18]-'0');
gsmTimeStruct.Minute    = (gsm_clk_string[20]-'0')*10 + (gsm_clk_string[21]-'0');
gsmTimeStruct.Second    = (gsm_clk_string[23]-'0')*10 + (gsm_clk_string[24]-'0');
TIMEZONE                = (gsm_clk_string[26]-'0')*10 + (gsm_clk_string[27]-'0');
CONEZONE                = gsm_clk_string[25];
```

Comment: Each ASCII digit can be converted subtracting `'0'` (`0x30`). BTW it is too broad for SO

Comment: If `sscanf` is too big, you're stuck manually moving along the string and parsing each number with `strtoul`/`atoi` or the like (and you're responsible for error checking, if errors are a possibility), or manual text conversion via ASCII math. Whether it actually saves anything is open to question (presumably `sscanf` might get reused in other places, reducing the amortized cost per use). Are you sure you need the space that badly, or is this just premature optimization?

Comment: @ShadowRanger Error checking is not an issue, I updated the post.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Yes, I need to save 2kilobytes on this application. Because my bootloader will overwrite it if the application size is larger than expected.

Comment: Do the parsing yourself.

Comment: I had tried parsing it myself using 'atoi' but I'm not sure it is the best way to do it.

Comment: A simple `for` is (probably) the smaller solution.

Comment: It have fixed position , so you can do manually easy. TIMEZONE=aoti(&gsm_clk_string[29]); CONEZONE=gsm_clk_string[28]; gsm_clk_string[28]=0; gsmTimeStruct.Second=atoi(&gsm_clk_string[26];gsm_clk_string[25]=0; ...

Comment: @abdullahcinar show your parsing code using `atoi`, otherwise we cannot give further advice about that code.

Comment: I don't know about @MichaelWalz, but if *I* had said "Do the parsing yourself" (as indeed I would have done had he not beaten me to it) then I would not have been talking about `atoi()`. I would have meant *manually*, without calling any function.  If I were to recommend a function, however, then it would be `strtol()`, not  `atoi()`.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I will try to write it manually from scratch as you and LPs suggested and compare it with the one that used `ato();`

Comment: @JohnBollinger I wasn't talking about `atoi` in first place. It was just a reply to the OP's comment where he mentioned `atoi`.

Comment: @MichaelWalz, I supposed you probably didn't, but not being psychic, I said, "I don't know about MichaelWalz."  I, too, raised `atoi()` because the OP had done, and indeed, I probably would not have commented at all otherwise.

Comment: Abdullah: a little trick: `(a-'0')*10+(b-'0')` is the same as `a*10+b-(11*'0')`, which saves one subtraction. Of course, it is possible that your compiler will find this optimization; you could check the compiled code.

Comment: Unrelated to memory consumption: You have `%hd` to read the `uint16` value; you use `%d`, though, to read the `uint8` values.  You should nominally be using `%hu` for the first and `%hhu` for the others.

Comment: @abdullahcinar Your edited code is not generalized, and all indices of string are wrong....

Comment: @rici Nice trick! I had not even tried to think about it, thanks :)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks for correcting. Actually that struct had different types of variables at first. I guess I forgot to change the specifiers when I changed the definitons of those variables. I missed it because it was working well but anyway I should change it now.

Comment: @LPs I had simplified the format to avoid distracting the main question, the year format has 2 digits actually, I edited the question now.. That code snippet works very well. What do you mean by generalizing it? The format is always the same, it only responds error or responds with this string, only after this I try to parse it. Thanks for the suggestion by the way :)

Answer (score 0):

I would think all you'd need is this, just move the char ptr accordingly.
In code example below i assume the first character in `gsm_clk_string` is `"`

```
/*                     "+CCLK: "2017/04/07, 12:57:43+03""    */
/*  gsm_clk_string[] : 0123456789012345678902134567890123    */

char *ptr;

ptr = gsm_clk_string;
ptr += 9;

gsmTimeStruct.Year = (uint16) ((*ptr - '0') * 1000);
ptr++;
gsmTimeStruct.Year += (uint16) ((*ptr - '0') * 100);
ptr++;
gsmTimeStruct.Year += (uint16) ((*ptr - '0') * 10);
ptr++;
gsmTimeStruct.Year += (uint16) ((*ptr - '0'));

ptr += 2;

gsmTimeStruct.Month = (uint8) ((*ptr - '0') * 10);
ptr++;
gsmTimeStruct.Month += (uint8) (*ptr - '0');

ptr += 2;

gsmTimeStruct.Day = (uint8) ((*ptr - '0') * 10);
ptr++;
gsmTimeStruct.Day += (uint8) (*ptr - '0');

ptr += 3;

gsmTimeStruct.Hour = (uint8) ((*ptr - '0') * 10);
ptr++;
gsmTimeStruct.Hour += (uint8) (*ptr - '0');

ptr += 2;

gsmTimeStruct.Minute = (uint8) ((*ptr - '0') * 10);
ptr++;
gsmTimeStruct.Minute += (uint8) (*ptr - '0');

ptr += 2;

gsmTimeStruct.Second = (uint8) ((*ptr - '0') * 10);
ptr++;
gsmTimeStruct.Second += (uint8) (*ptr - '0');

ptr++;

if ( *ptr == '+' )
{
   ptr++;
   TIMEZONE = (whatever_type_TimeZone) ((*ptr - '0') * 10);
   ptr++
   TIMEZONE += (whatever_type_TimeZone) ((*ptr - '0'));

   unixTime = (uint32_t) RTC_DateTimeToUnix( gsmTimeStruct ) - ( TIMEZONE * 3600 );    
}
else if ( *ptr == '-' )
{
   ptr++;
   TIMEZONE = (whatever_type_TimeZone) ((*ptr - '0') * 10);
   ptr++
   TIMEZONE += (whatever_type_TimeZone) ((*ptr - '0'));

   unixTime = (uint32_t) RTC_DateTimeToUnix( gsmTimeStruct ) + ( TIMEZONE * 3600 );
}
else
{
    /* problem */
}
```

Comment: You should improve your code using a function like `int convert(char *buffer, int digit)`

Comment: I'don't know about a function, but I'd certainly at least use a loop.  I suspect that either of those could yield smaller compiled code.

Comment: I wrote it manually and edited my question. I will try this also and see the difference. Also, I would appreciate if you guys can say your comments on that snippet.